# Update foreign key of one model based on another model

Tags: python, django

I have a student model:

```
class Student(User):
    religion = models.ForeignKey(
        Religion, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    caste = models.ForeignKey(Caste, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    phone_number1 = models.CharField(
        "Phone Number 1", max_length=10)
    phone_number2 = models.CharField(
        "Phone Number 2 (optional)", max_length=10, blank=True)
    classes = models.ForeignKey(
        Class, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name+" "+self.last_name

    # Control model features
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Student'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Students'
```

And an admission model:

```
class Admission(models.Model):
    admission_date = models.DateField()
    classes = models.ForeignKey(
        Class, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Also a class model that takes in all the information of the class the student is in:

```
class Class(models.Model):

    class_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        default=None
    )
    division_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        default=None
    )
    class_teacher = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    institute = models.ForeignKey(
        Institute, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name+" "+self.division_name+" "+self.institute.name

    # Control model features
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Class'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Classes'
```

I want to achieve the following: change student info based on the admissions model. When I update the Admission info, it should take the class and update the class in the student model based on the class provided in the admission model. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Take a look at Django signals.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to use signal?

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender= Admission)  # it works after saving (created or updated)
def update_student_info(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # change student info based on the admissions model
    admission_class = instance.classes
    admission_student = instance.student
    admission_student.classes = admission_class
    admission_student.save()
```